# How to use Mustache with javax.mail spring boot to send an email

Tags: spring, spring-boot, mustache

After a long research I found an example of sending an email using mustache and javax.mail but I don't know why spring boot doesnt read the html inside .mustache file. anyone please

My Controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "send", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String sendEmail( EmailDTO emailDto) throws MessagingException {
        final String fromEmail = "validemail.com"; //requires valid gmail id
        final String password = "password"; // correct password for gmail id
        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com"); //SMTP Host
        props.put("mail.smtp.port", "587"); //TLS Port
        props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true"); //enable authentication
        props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true"); //enable STARTTLS
        Authenticator auth = new Authenticator() {
            //override the getPasswordAuthentication method
            protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                return new PasswordAuthentication(fromEmail, password);
            }
        };

        MustacheFactory mf = new DefaultMustacheFactory();
        Mustache m = mf.compile("templates/email.mustache");

        StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
        String messageText = "MUSTACHE-MESSAGETEXT";
        try {
            m.execute(writer, emailDto).flush();
            messageText = writer.toString();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        Session session = Session.getInstance(props, auth);
        Message message = new MimeMessage(session);
        message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, InternetAddress.parse("validemail.com"));
        message.setSubject("MUSTACHE-SUBJECT");
        message.setText(messageText);
        Transport.send(message);

        return "sendEmail";
    }
```

my email.mustache

```
{{# fromEmail }}
   {{ . }}
{{/ fromEmail }}
```

application.properties:

```
spring.mail.host=smtp.gmail.com
spring.mail.port=587
spring.mail.username=validemail@gmail.com
spring.mail.password=password
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.auth=true
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.starttls.enable=true
spring.mustache.prefix = classpath:/templates/
spring.mustache.suffix = .mustache
```

At the end I want to send an email with a colored table that ahs data
Thanks.

Comment: Apart from the properties there is nothing Spring related in here, nor it there any HTML in your template. So no HTML will ever be magically created. Nor are the properties used as everything you do for sending mail bypasses the automated setup that Sprig Boot does.